# Can FIDE rated open tournaments have games played without chess clocks?

Tags: fide, tournament, chess-clocks

So there was this FIDE rated tournament with 750+ participants and the last boards games were played without clocks. This was probably due to shortage of clocks. Anyway the last boards were occupied almost all by kids who are probably very new to chess (know how to move pieces and probably doesn't how to use a chess clock) so it might have no effect that no clocks were used.

The rest of the games were played with 90 minutes+ 30s increment/move. The FIDE tournament report mention says `Time Control     Standard: 90 minutes with 30 second increment from move 1`.

My question is if this is allowed by FIDE rules to have games played without clocks for FIDE rated events.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is playing without a clock, with the arbiter adding the clock when the game goes too long, within FIDE rules?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/38773/is-playing-without-a-clock-with-the-arbiter-adding-the-clock-when-the-game-goes)

Comment: @letmewinpls45 "So, what you describe is allowed within FIDE rules for chess but the games `may` not be FIDE rated" was a bit unclear

Comment: That means the game is valid FIDE games(none of the moves break the FIDE rule of chess), but the game will not be FIDE rated (you can't gain any elo from the game). It's like an online chess game, the game itself is valid but you can't gain any FIDE ratings.

Comment: but if the results are sent in fide tournament report

Comment: fide profiles have been created for the players from this tournament. so technically they are eligible for rating perf/gain/loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if this is allowed by FIDE rules to have games played without clocks for FIDE rated events

The answer is that, yes, this is allowed. FIDE used to rate tournaments not games but for many years now that has been reversed and FIDE rates games not tournaments. So, individual games that are played by FIDE registered players using clocks in an event which has been registered for FIDE rating will be rated by FIDE and games that do not satisfy all the necessary criteria will not be rated.

Normally it is the responsibility of the chief arbiter and the federation responsible to only supply valid data to FIDE. That is, the games which don't qualify for FIDE rating should not be reported in the TRF16.

The part of FIDE which is responsible for ratings is the [Qualification Commission](https://ratings.fide.com/fide_directory.phtml?content=6) and as you can see from the link the current chairmen is Bermudan [Nick Faulks](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/8800103).

[Here](https://www.ecforum.org.uk/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6021&p=126771#p126771) is Nick commenting on another matter (what happens when the arbiter repairs two players whose opponents didn't turn up but gives them less time than for the competition as a whole) in the English Chess Forum in 2013 making the point that FIDE rates games individually.

> At first I was puzzled by this discussion. **FIDE rates games individually**, so a game is a game. But how do you report it? In a given round, AvB is 1-0 def, CvD is 1-0 def, but then the game AvC takes place. What has happened? If that game, because it starts late, is played under a faster time control, that may also be a problem. I don't know the answers.

Comment: so the games played without the clocks should not go into the tournament report published by FIDE?

Comment: The TRF16 (Tournament Report Form version 2016) which is produced by the Chief Arbiter, sent to the federation where the tournament is being played and then sent by the federation to FIDE should not contain the games played without clocks and then these game results should not appear on the FIDE website when FIDE process the file.